# Threading - help updating Kivy GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, updating

I am quite new to python and read through several forums as well as having been trying to fix this problem for many days.
I have a GUI (Kivy), try to get an ip-camera's image and keep updating my GUI with the latest image. My problem is that the GUI freezes, but I can see that my function is working in the background: every time I click on the window and resize it a little bit the GUI is updated to the latest frame at this point of time. I tried to solve this by threading, but it is not working:

```
#this is my main function
def main(self, *args):
    global adjustment_stop_threading
    global adjustment_lock
    global adjustment_frame
    
    #here I am starting the other function that gets the current live image (below)
    threading.Thread(target=self.getimage_livestream).start()
 
    #"my_frame" should be empty at the Beginning
    my_frame = None
        
    while True:
        #grab lock
        with adjustment_lock:
            #proceed if there is a live_image in "adjustment_frame" 
            if not adjustment_frame is None:
                #we copy here to dump the lock as fast as possible
                my_frame = np.copy(adjustment_frame)
            
        if my_frame is not None:
            try:
                #do some image processing to be able to display the image
                buf1 = cv2.flip(my_frame, 0)
                buf = buf1.tobytes()
                image_texture = Texture.create(size=(my_frame.shape[1], my_frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='rgb')
                image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')
                #here we replace the kivy texture "liveimageadjustment.texture" with our image "image_texture" that comes from              processing "my_frame" before
                self.root.ids.liveimageadjustment.texture = image_texture
                #sleep to allow the GUI to update...(but is it not working!)
                time.sleep(0.03)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                #no Exception is printed here, because everything is working fine in general...except updating the GUI!
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break
 
            
#this function connects to the ip-camera, gets and rotates the current image. Then saves the current image in global variable "adjustment_frame"
def getimage_livestream(self, *args):
        global adjustment_stop_threading
        global adjustment_lock
        global adjustment_frame
 
        stream = urlopen('http://192.168.4.1:81/stream')
        bytes = b''
        while not adjustment_stop_threading:
            try:
                bytes += stream.read(1024) 
                a = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd8') 
                b = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd9')
                if a != -1 and b != -1: 
                    jpg = bytes[a:b+2] 
                    bytes = bytes[b+2:]
                    getliveimage = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(jpg, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
                    livestreamrotated1 = cv2.rotate(getliveimage, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE) #here I am rotating the image
                    
                    with adjustment_lock:
                        adjustment_frame = livestreamrotated1
 
                    time.sleep(0.03)
 
            except Exception as e:
                #no Exception is printed here, because everything is working fine in this function
                print(e)
                print("failed at this point")
```

Comment: Many GUIs don't support multithreading because it can interfere with their own processing of user-input and updating of UI widgets. Kivy may be one of them. Search this site for questions specifically about these two and you be able to find a workaround. Note that using `time.sleep()` often causes similar issues (for the same reason).

Comment: I think this is possible with kivy, I am just not using threading the way I should...